# Same Code, Same Browser, Different Machines = Different Form Layout

Tags: css, ajax, html

I developed a web app in PHP/HTML5/JavaScript/CSS... and am mow having a CSS issue which I don't understand.

- On my PC, the code lays out how I want it to
- On my friend's PC, it shows differently
- Same version of Chrome in use.

The issue is when I update the form to show extra rows via JavaScript/Ajax.  As soon as those rows come on screen, it's ALL bad.  Here's some pictures:

1.) My friend's computer when the new form lines load (problem in fieldset "Split Transaction Details"):
[COSMOS Form - New Rows - Wierd](https://app.box.com/s/epvcdjmo47tycvvyas0l)

2.) My computer when the new form lines load:
[COSMOS Form - New Rows - Expected](https://app.box.com/s/s5zo14e7aaqt8qs4to5b)

Code snippet from my PHP/HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script>
            function SplitTrans(num) {
                var xmlhttp;

                var n = document.getElementById("numsplit");
                var splitnum = n.options[n.selectedIndex].value;

                document.getElementById("transMasterCat").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("transSubCat").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("transAmount").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("transStudent").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("transMemo").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("transParticipant").setAttribute('class', 'label-lb');
                document.getElementById("transPaymentMethod").setAttribute('class', 'label-lb');

                if (num == "0")
                {
                    document.getElementById("splitRows").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("transMasterCat").readOnly = false;
                    document.getElementById("transSubCat").readOnly = false;
                    document.getElementById("transAmount").readOnly = false;
                    document.getElementById("transStudent").readOnly = false;
                    document.getElementById("transMemo").readOnly = false;
                    document.getElementById("transParticipant").setAttribute('class', 'label-l');
                    document.getElementById("transPaymentMethod").setAttribute('class', 'label-l');

                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("splitRows").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "split-ar.php?splitnum=" + splitnum, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
        ...
        <form action="acctsrecv.php" method="post">
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend">Add New Accounts Receivable Transaction</legend>
                    <fieldset class="fieldset2">
                        <legend class="legend">Transaction Split Option</legend>
                        <label for "transSplitNum" class="label-l">Number Of Parts: </label><select name='numsplit' id="numsplit"><option value='0'>Select</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option></select><br />
                        <input type="button" class="button" Value="Split" onclick="SplitTrans(1)" /> <input type="button" class="button" Value="Clear" onclick="SplitTrans(0)" /><br />
                    </fieldset>
        ...
        </fieldset>
                <div id="splitRows">

                </div>
```

As per comments, here's my CSS:

```
/* Original CSS assembled by Marko Mihelcic at mcville and James Koster from sixshootermedia*/

html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size:0.74em;
    color:#555555;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
}

a {
    color:#4D87CE;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#2a65ad;
}

ol,ul {

}

li {
    list-style-image:url(../images/backgrounds/li.gif);
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:left;
}

.debug { 
    border:1px dashed red;
}

#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
   /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

#menu {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    background-image:url('../images/backgrounds/back.png');
}

#menu a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;

}

#menu a:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left:1px solid #243482;
    border-right:1px solid #243482;
    padding-left:9px;
    padding-right:9px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/hover.jpg);
}

#header {
    width:925px;
    /*height: 92px;*/
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    /*border: 1px solid gray;*/
}

#header h1 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:5px;
    color:#253183;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:left;
}

#header h2 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#content {
    width:925px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
    padding-bottom:54px; /* Total height of the footer */
    overflow: auto;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}

/*.introduction {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#99B198;
    text-indent:25px;
    background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/desc.jpg);
    background-position:bottom left;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:200px;
    padding-bottom:35px;
    padding-top:0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}*/

.logo {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

#sidebar {
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    font-size:95%;
    color:#253183;
    text-align:left;
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

#sidebar .badlogin {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

#sidebar h1 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
    color:#253183;
    text-align:right;
}

#sidebar .fieldset {
    //border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    border: none;
    width:131px;
}

#sidebar .input {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar .button {
     border: none;
     background: url('../images/backgrounds/up.png') no-repeat top left;
     padding: 2px 8px;
     margin-top: 5px;
 }

#sidebar .button:hover {
     border: none;
     background: url('../images/backgrounds/pressed.png') no-repeat top left;
     padding: 2px 8px;
 }

#sidebar .label {
     display: inline;
     width: 131px;
     float: left;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     border: none;
 }

#sidebar br { 
    clear: left;
}

.submenu {
}

.submenu a {
    display:block;
    width:95%;
    background-image:url('../images/backgrounds/submenua.png');
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:0;
}

.submenu a:hover {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    background-image:url('../images/backgrounds/submenua.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#mainbar {
    margin-right:155px;
    padding-right:5px;
    background-image:url('../images/backgrounds/mainbar.jpg');
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#mainbar ol {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

#mainbar ol li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
}

#mainbar ul {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

#mainbar ul li {
    list-style: square outside none;
}

#mainbar .nologin {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

#mainbar .warning {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

#mainbar h1 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
    color:#253183;
}

#mainbar .h1a {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    //text-transform:uppercase;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #253183;
    color:#253183;
}

#mainbar h2 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#253183;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#mainbar .h2a {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#253183;
    border-bottom:1px solid #253183;
}

#mainbar h3 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#253183;
}

#mainbar .h3a {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#253183;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#mainbar p {
    padding:5px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#mainbar figcaption {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#mainbar .articleimg {
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#mainbar .articleimg2 {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

#mainbar .table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:2px solid #253183;
}

#mainbar .th {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #253183;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

#mainbar .td1 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: black;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

#mainbar .td2 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #BBD9F3;
    color: #000000;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: black;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

#mainbar .fieldset {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:740px;
}

#mainbar .fieldset2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*width:740px;*/
}

#mainbar .legend {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#mainbar .label-l {
     display: inline;
     width: 131px;
     float: left;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     //border: 1px solid red;
 }

 #mainbar .label-lb {
     display: inline;
     width: 131px;
     float: left;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     font-weight: bold;
     //border: 1px solid red;
 }

#mainbar .input-l {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#mainbar .label-r {
     display: inline;
     width: 131px;
     float: right;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     //border: 1px solid red;
 }

#mainbar .label-rb {
     display: inline;
     width: 131px;
     float: right;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     font-weight: bold;
     //border: 1px solid red;
 }

#mainbar .input-r {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: right;
}

#mainbar .label-l2 {
     display: inline;
     width: 240px;
     float: left;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     //order: 1px solid red;
 }

#mainbar .input-l2 {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#mainbar .label-r2 {
     display: inline;
     width: 240px;
     float: right;
     margin: 2px 4px 6px 4px;
     text-align: left;
     //border: 1px solid red;
 }

#mainbar .input-r2 {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: #ffc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: right;
}

#mainbar .txta {
    width: 704px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#mainbar .txta2 {
    width: 704px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#mainbar .txta3 {
    width: 680px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#mainbar .button {
     border: none;
     background: url('../images/backgrounds/up.png') no-repeat top left;
     padding: 2px 8px;
     margin-top: 5px;
}

#mainbar .button:hover {
     border: none;
     background: url('../images/backgrounds/pressed.png') no-repeat top left;
     padding: 2px 8px;
 }

#mainbar .submit {
     clear: both;
     postition: relative;
     left:341px;
 }

 #mainbar .center {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

#mainbar br { 
    clear: left;
}

#footer {
    /* width:80%; */
    background-color:#253183;
    border-top:1px solid #81C0FF;
    border-bottom:5px solid #253169;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -54px; /* Total height of the footer */
    clear: both;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:38px;   /* Height of the footer */
    text-align: center;
}

#footer a {
    color:#81C0FF;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color:#AFD7FF;
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Did you clear the cache in your machine?

Comment: Different machines can have different resolutions , read about responsive design. This should answer your question.

Comment: It’s apparently the CSS code that matters, but it was not disclosed at all. You should eliminate the possibility of Ajax playing any role here, by testing with some sample static content. In general, do as much debugging and problem isolation as you can, and post a minimal example that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Updated my question with CSS... apologies for leaving it out...